# Does Performance.measure() work on browser's main thread?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

My intent is to determine if using [`Performance.measure()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure) negatively affects the performance of a webapp. I'm trying to decide if its worth invoking it in production or whether to only use it for non-production deployments/local development. Please elaborate beyond my title question as appropriate.

Obviously it requires some CPU cycles and memory but I'm curious if the work happens on the main UI thread?

Finally if anyone has any metrics surrounding the performance impact please do share. Thanks.

Comment: Um its js, js runs in the js-parser which usually runs on the main thread? And why do you even care? Do you encounter problems?

Comment: @JonasW [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) are an example of JS that doesn't run on the main thread. No I haven't encountered problems; I just care because I want to make a thoughtful engineering decision.

Comment: but we are not talking about web workers here. Imo its totally fine to use Performance.measure in production. I dont think that it will impact performance

Comment: It simply exposes the existing metrics from the browser's internal code. Anyway, you can measure the overhead it adds on your real code and then decide.